# Is it possible to continuously harvest asparagus?

Tags: perennials, harvesting, greenhouse, asparagus

Like this:

[image]

From what I understand:

- It's a perennial that emits spears from a central crown - those are what we eat.
- If we don't eat the spears, they turn into ferns. Those ferns absorb sunshine and fuel the growth of the crown.
- The crown absorbs nutrients from its root system, and underwrites the formation of spears.
- As the crown gets bigger, it can fuel more (and bigger) spears.
- We generally only harvest for about a month out of the year, because we need to support the needs of the crown (carb accumulation).

I'm trying to keep things simple and convenient as I design my garden. Instead of putting our harvest on a calendar, could we:

- Build a year-round greenhouse (I'm in Zone 5b)
- Plant a bunch of crowns
- Cultivate them for a few years - no harvesting whatsoever. Just load up the carbohydrate reserves and fuel the growth of the crown and its root system with compost/biochar/etc
- After a few years, cut 50% of the ferns down, per crown, so that 50% of the spears-turned-ferns are collecting nutrients that provide for a continuous harvest of spears, year-round, no calendar needed?

Bonus Q:

- Does the asparagus plant really need winter? Is there anything in its DNA that activates critical biological mechanisms in response to cold seasons?

Comment: The tops will die back every winter. But they are a good marker when looking for wild asparagus in the spring; the conical shape and gold-like color are diagnostic.

Comment: "Does the asparagus plant really need winter?" Most "non-tropical climate" plants have an annual growth cycle controlled day length, temperature, or both. Of course you could subvert that with a controlled environment to get a crop at any time of the year, but if you permanently *remove* what triggers the cycle, the plant won't thrive.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "continuously". I would pick until new stalks were under roughly 3/8" ( 10 mm). Although I see some stalks in the store at 1/4". That is I would harvest on the basis of only size. Apparently it does need winter as i now live in Zone 8 and see no local asparagus. Footnote: When I lived in Zone 5 , I knew of an unused asparagus farm ( about 2 acres ). We picked it once , stalks to 3" + and tender ( so much for the folklore about size ). We returned to find a neighbor owned it and chased anyone away who trespassed ; he never picked it.